# Jest encountered an unexpected token (html)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

React based application moving unit tests from mocha to jest. Getting the following error:

[image: jest error]

I've tried quite a few different plugins, transforms, etc. and can't seem to find the right nail for this issue. Best guess right now is that I'm missing a config piece somewhere along the chain.The code renders as expected in the wild, jest just isn't a fan of testing it.

Babel version: 6.26.0

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env"],
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
    "react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["env"], ["es2015"], "react"]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy", 
    "lodash", 
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    ["react-intl", { "messagesDir": "./src/translations" }]
  ]
}
```

jest block in package.json

```
"jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@abstractions/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/abstractions/$1",
      "@store/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/store/$1",
      "@styles/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/styles/$1",
      "@translations/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/translations/$1",
      "@utils/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/utils/$1"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
```

EDIT - 1600
Breaking code: this is where the error trips but is only tangentially related to the testing code itself. It's a part of our auth process that's getting hit before we hit the page to be tested.

```
import { AppLayout } from '@components/AppLayout';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { injectIntl, intlShape, defineMessages, InjectedIntlProps as IInjectedIntlProps } from 'react-intl';
import { InvalidPermission } from '@components/invalidPermission/InvalidPermission';
import { preventPropagation } from '@utils/preventPropagation';

const store = require('store') as any;

const messages = defineMessages({  
  pageTitle: {
    id: 'accessDenied.pageTitle',
    defaultMessage: 'Access Denied'
  },
  message: {
    id: 'accessDenied.message',
    defaultMessage: 'Access denied to one or more resources you requested. Try again or login with a different account.'
  },
  link: {
    id: 'accessDenied.link',
    defaultMessage: 'Try page again'
  },
});

class AccessDeniedBase extends React.Component<IInjectedIntlProps, undefined> {

  static propTypes: React.ValidationMap<any> = {
    intl: intlShape.isRequired
  };

  tryPageAgain = (e: any) => {
    preventPropagation(e);

    const preAuthLocation: string = store.get('preAuthLocation');
    document.location.replace(preAuthLocation);

    return false;
  }

  render() {
    const { intl } = this.props;
    const title = intl.formatMessage(messages.pageTitle);
    const message = intl.formatMessage(messages.pageTitle);

    const preAuthLocation: string = store.get('preAuthLocation');

    const extraSection = preAuthLocation == null ? null : (<p>
      <Link to={preAuthLocation} onClick={this.tryPageAgain}>{intl.formatMessage(messages.link)}</Link>
    </p>);

    return (<div>
      <AppLayout color='accent' hasFooter={true} title={title} pageTitle={title}>
        <InvalidPermission message={message} extraSection={extraSection} />
      </AppLayout>
    </div>);
  }

  //#endregion
}

export const AccessDenied = injectIntl<any>(AccessDeniedBase as any) as any;
```

Test code: .spec.ts file. Should be testing our client page code. There's still a little leftover mocha code (such as MochaDone) but I don't believe that's a factor in the current error

```
import { GuidEmpty } from './../utils/guid';
import { IClient } from './../abstractions/domain/IClient.d';
import '../../testHelper';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as actions from '../actions/clients';
import { clients } from './clients';

const api = {
  mockOutClient: (clientId: any) => Promise.resolve({
    clientId,
    companyName: 'Adams, Blanda and Bernier',
    companyDescription: 'Oil & Gas Production',
    country: 'United States',
    latitude: 41.76,
    longitude: -72.74,
    url: 'http://maps.google.com/?ll=41.76,-72.74',
  })
};

const baseClient = { 
  createdById: '6ac20d02-e4eb-4ef4-9543-6e16a9d57aaf',
  createdOn: '2017-08-25T14:27:00.942Z' as any as Date,
  updatedOn: '2017-08-25T14:27:00.942Z' as any as Date,
  customFieldsData: {'5199cf80-bc06-49d9-8a93-2272e6985b0e':'Unit tests!!!'},
};

const blankClient: IClient = {
  id: GuidEmpty,
  isActive: true,
  companyName: '',
  description: '',
};

const initialState: IClient[] = [
  {
    ...baseClient,
    id: '56fc0e3a-3d81-45f6-b5fa-cf8f300330b8',
    description: 'Client desc 1',
    companyName: 'Client 1',
  },
  {
    ...baseClient,
    id: 'd1903b6a-674c-47e0-bf22-48fa86de358b',
    description: 'Client desc 2',
    companyName: 'Client 2',
  },
  {
    ...baseClient,
    id: '56448b0c-73fb-46b6-acf9-1696560d48cb',
    description: 'Client desc 3',
    companyName: 'Client 3',
  },
  {
    ...baseClient,
    id: '33ca54f1-aaa6-4d25-a970-7b231932e515',
    description: 'Client desc 4',
    companyName: 'Client 4',
  },
];

const initialStateBackup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState));

describe('reducers clients', () => {
  test(actions.mockOutClient.type + ': should properly update with mock data', (done: MochaDone) => {

    const tempClient = { ...blankClient };

    const newState = clients(initialState, actions.createTempClient.getAction(tempClient) as any);
    const newStateBackup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newState));


    expect(initialState, 'Initial state was modified').to.eql(initialStateBackup);

    expect(newState).to.be.length(initialState.length + 1);
    initialState.forEach((client, index) => expect(client).to.be.eql(newState[index]));
    expect(newState[newState.length - 1]).to.be.eql(tempClient);

    const updatedFields = ['companyName', 'description'];

    const clientIndex = newState.findIndex(q => q.id === GuidEmpty);
    expect(clientIndex).to.be.greaterThan(-1);

    api.mockOutClient(GuidEmpty)
      .then((payload: any) => {
        const newTempState = clients(newState, { 
          type: actions.mockOutClient.completed, 
          payload
        } as any);

        expect(initialState, 'Initial state was modified').to.eql(initialStateBackup);
        expect(newState, 'New state was modified').to.eql(newStateBackup);

        updatedFields.forEach(q => expect((newTempState[clientIndex] as any)[q], 
          `${q} should not be null or empty`).to.not.be.null.and.not.empty);

        done();

      })
      .catch(done);
  });
  test(actions.createTempClient.type + ' & ' + actions.createTempClient.type + ': should properly add/update', () => {

    const tempClient = { ...blankClient };

    const newState = clients(initialState, actions.createTempClient.getAction(tempClient));

    expect(initialState, 'Initial state was modified').to.eql(initialStateBackup);

    expect(newState).to.be.length(initialState.length + 1);
    initialState.forEach((client, index) => expect(client).to.be.eql(newState[index]));
    expect(newState[newState.length - 1]).to.be.eql(tempClient);

    // now remove test

    const removedState = clients(newState, actions.removeTempClient.getAction(null));
    expect(removedState).to.be.length(initialState.length);
    initialState.forEach((client, index) => expect(client).to.be.eql(removedState[index]));

  });
});
```

Comment: My first guess is you might need to assign the test as an object. can you try wrapping the `div`s with paranthasis? like `(<div/>)`

Comment: Negative, same issue when I wrap the component in parenthesis

Comment: have you added moduleNameMapper files in your root directory

Comment: Could you please share the source file that you're trying to test and test file source? It's hard to find the error without seeing the code. Also, you don't need `es2015` babel preset as `env` preset already includes it.

Comment: @OleksandrKovpashko - updated the initial post with further details